# onDestroy не отрабатывает

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, activity-life-cycle

Мне необходимо, чтобы при закрытии приложения сохранялись данные через Shared Preference. Пытался засунуть вызов метода сохранения в onDestroy mainActivity, но при закрытии приложения он не отрабатывает. Как сохранить данные?

Comment: при каждой их смене. если у человека сядет зарядка или выпадет аккумулятор, то никакой колбэк не поможет

Comment: перенесите логику в onStop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте onStop. Метод onDestroy вызывается когда ОС уничтожает саму Activity а не тогда, когда она закрывается. Ммежду закрытием и уничтожением может пройти достаточно много времени, минут 15 если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Вообще-то всё почти наоборот. Если закрыть активити кнопкой назад или вызвать финиш, то `onDestroy()` как раз и вызовется. А если активити будет уничтожать система (нехватка памяти, убийство процесса путём смахивания из recent apps), то вызов `onDestroy()` не гарантируется. Вы видимо перепутали уничтожение активити, с очисткой памяти, которую занимало это активити.

Comment: Может быть надо проверить